Update 10k records twice a day with sObject collection API
We have a requirement to update 10k records twice a day. Business has rejected the idea to use Bulk API due to its non-transactional property. What we have identified is using sObject collection with composite API to update 1000 records at one go. (5 subRequest, 200 records each)
We were wondering what would be the best approach to do this ten times?
We will be using mule, so if any additional information related to mule can be provided, it would be great!
